# Replace Canon 600D with Canon 80D?

Tags: canon, video, canon-600d, canon-80d

I have a Canon 600D which has served me well over the years. Now I would like to create more video content, but the 600D has this 12min video length limit. The result is quite often that the camera just turns off in the middle of a speech, interrupting everything.

I have read that the Canon 80D does good video and has a good autofocus and a touchscreen to select what object to focus on. But I still wonder about whether it is worth buying the 80D to replace the 600D.

Is there a video limit in the 80D like in the 600D? If yes, is there any way to break that limit?

Comment: In some countries (France, IIRC), some video recording tax applies to devices that can record more than X minutes in a single recording. Consequently some devices that can theoretically make longer recordings but where video isn't the prime function are restricted by software to avoid paying that tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered Magic Lantern for your 600D?  From their [FAQ](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/faq):

> **How do I record for more than 12 minutes?**
>
> **H.264:**
>
> - Lower the `bitrate` (CBR 0.4 will let you record continuously for 30 minutes).
> - Use `Movie restart`, but you will lose a few seconds when a new file is created.
> - Technically, there's no 12 minute limit. There's a 30 minute limit and a 4 GB limit, whichever comes first. With default bitrate settings, the 4 GB limit is reached after around 12 minutes (more or less).
>
> **RAW:**
>
> - Can record continuously until the card gets full (no 30-minute limit).
> - File sizes are huge; you may want to reduce resolution and/or FPS; also use a large card.
> - exFAT recommended; otherwise, when creating a new 4GB segment, the speed drops a bit and recording may stop.
>
> **External HDMI recorder:**
>
> - Enable the Clear Overlays feature to hide the focus box and the 16:9 bars.
> - Make the half-shutter button sticky (Prefs menu) to prevent the camera from turning off LiveView after 30 minutes.

Comment: @Socrates Please note that there is no ML for the 80D, which is why I'm still sticking to my 70D. You should definitely look into ML before making any decision, if you want to upgrade, I'd recommend the 70D. It's amazing for videos, and ML adds a LOT of features and fun to it.

Comment: Or one could check to see if there is aversion of ML available for the 600D that would allow it to shoot video for longer than 12 minutes. But where's the fun in not getting to spend a lot of money on a newer camera?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Canon 80D User Manual, page 310](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300022720/01/EOS_80D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf):

> **Movie Shooting Time Limit**
>
> The maximum recording time of one movie clip is 29 min. 59 sec. If the movie shooting time reaches 29 min. 59 sec., the movie shooting will stop automatically. You can start shooting a movie again by pressing the  button. (The movie will be recorded as a new movie file.)

Now, depending on the movie format and frame rate, your movie might be chopped up into 4 GiB-file chunks. This is probably done for compatibility reasons (file sizes on FAT32 filesystems are limited to 4 GiB), even though the 80D supposedly is capable of using memory cards formatted with ExFAT (which is not limited by 4 GiB file size limits). The recording duration based on format and frame rate is covered on page 309 of the manual.